# Prove that matrix can be divided by 17

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

We have been given $144228, 532270, 257567, 209270, 289017, 519792$ which are divisible by $17$. Show that:
$$
        \begin{matrix}
        1 & 4&  4&  2&  2&  8 \\
        5 & 3 & 2 & 2 & 7 & 0\\
        2 & 5  &7&5&  6  &7 \\
        2  &0  &9  &2  &7  &0 \\
        2  &8 & 9  &0  &1 & 7 \\
        5  &1&  9 & 7  &9&  2  \\
        \end{matrix}
$$
is also divided by $17$.

Try to do it without calculating the determinant of the matrix.

Hint: $\Bbb{Z}$ and elementary elimination.

Ok, my idea is using elementary elimination get matrix looks like:
$$
        \begin{matrix}
        1 & 4&  17x4&  2&  2&  8 \\
        5 & 3 & 17a2 & 2 & 7 & 0\\
        2 & 5  &17b7&5&  6  &7 \\
        2  &0  &17c9  &2  &7  &0 \\
        2  &8 & 17d9  &0  &1 & 7 \\
        5  &1&  17f9 & 7  &9&  2  \\
        \end{matrix}
$$
Then, can I take out $17$ before matrix? That's correct way? When I get $17$ before matrix is prove that is divided by $17$?

Comment: Are you asking how to show that the *determinant* of the matrix is divisible by $17$? If that is the case, you should edit your question to make that clear.  If not, please explain what you mean by a matrix being divisible by an integer. Cheers!

Comment: @MatthewConroy to be honest im not sure in task we have been given these numbers which are divisible  by 17. I need to show that matrix  is also divisible by 17 that's all what is in this task.

Comment: Well that is unclear then.  Do you have an instructor? You should ask them for clarification.

Comment: @MatthewConroy it is the determinant. Trick question...

Answer (score 1):

Think of the matrix as having coefficients in the field $\mathbb Z / 17 \mathbb Z.$ We have the column vector of integers
$$
X =
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
100000 \\
10000 \\
1000 \\
100 \\
10 \\
1
\end{array}
\right)
$$
which is not the zero vector in this vector space, all entries are nonzero $\pmod{17}.$
If your square matrix is called $A,$
we find
$$ AX = 0. $$
That is, the matrix is not full rank, there is an eigenvalue $0.$ Regarded as over the integers, this means this determinant is divisible by $17$

Comment: so i have to multiply A and your X matrix? If yes what then?

Answer (score 1):

> my idea is using elementary elimination get matrix looks like ...

That's the right idea, with the note that adding a multiple of a column to another column does not change the value of the determinant.

Multiply the first column by $10^5$, the second one by $10^4$ and so on until the fifth column gets multiplied by $10$, then add all of them to the last column. This will get you the original $6$ numbers in the last column, each of them divisible by 17, so you can then factor $17$ out of the determinant.

Answer (score 0):

$144228,532270,257567,209270,289017,519792=$

$\begin{bmatrix}10^{30}&10^{24}&10^{18}& 10^{12}&10^{6}&1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 4&  4&  2&  2&  8 \\
        5 & 3 & 2 & 2 & 7 & 0\\
        2 & 5  &7&5&  6  &7 \\
        2  &0  &9  &2  &7  &0 \\
        2  &8 & 9  &0  &1 & 7 \\
        5  &1&  9 & 7  &9&  2  \\
        \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}10^5\\10^4\\10^3\\10^2\\10\\1\end{bmatrix}$

Now convert to modulo 17

$\begin{bmatrix} 8&16&15&16&9&1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 4&  4&  2&  2&  8 \\
        5 & 3 & 2 & 2 & 7 & 0\\
        2 & 5  &7&5&  6  &7 \\
        2  &0  &9  &2  &7  &0 \\
        2  &8 & 9  &0  &1 & 7 \\
        5  &1&  9 & 7  &9&  2  \\
        \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}6\\4\\14\\15\\10\\1\end{bmatrix}$

And that product is divisible by 17.

However, if you multiply the just the right two matrices, you will get a column that is equivalent the zero vector in $\mathbb Z_{17}$ and there is no need to multiply the $3^{rd}$ matrix.

and if you want to keep the numbers a little smaller you could say:

$\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 4&  4&  2&  2&  8 \\
        5 & 3 & 2 & 2 & 7 & 0\\
        2 & 5  &7&5&  6  &7 \\
        2  &0  &9  &2  &7  &0 \\
        2  &8 & 9  &0  &1 & 7 \\
        5  &1&  9 & 7  &9&  2  \\
        \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}6\\4\\-3\\-2\\10\\1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}34\\102\\68\\51\\34\\85\end{bmatrix}\equiv \mathbf 0 \pmod{17}$